# export text then image in excel or pdf with dataexporter

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I am using primefaces 3.4.2 jar.I have one datatable with image in one column and I want to export given text rather then exported value for graphic image "org.primefaces.component.graphicimage.GraphicImage@578a5496" in excel.

```
<p:dataTable id="Data" var="data" value="#{bean.List}">

<p:column style="width:3%">
    <f:facet name="header">
        <h:outputText value="Value"></h:outputText> 
    </f:facet>
    <h:graphicImage style="border:0;" name="image1.png" library ="images" rendered="#{data.image eq 'image1'}"/>
    <h:graphicImage style="border:0;" name="image2.png" library ="images" rendered="#{data.image eq 'image2'"/>
</p:column>

</p:dataTable>

<h:commandLink id="excelDataExporterLink">
    <h:graphicImage id="searchExce1" name="excel1.png" library="images"></h:graphicImage>
    <p:dataExporter type="xls" target="Data" fileName="Data" pageOnly="true" />
</h:commandLink>
```

I want to export text `image1/image2` to corresponding Value column. Currently text `org.primefaces.component.graphicimage.GraphicImage@578a5496` will be exported
in excel or pdf.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to  extend the `ExcelExporter` (I guess that similar thing can be done with PDFExporter too), like this:

Notice that the value will be taken from the `alt` attribute,

```
public class ExtendedExcelExporter extends ExcelExporter {

@Override
protected String exportValue(FacesContext context, UIComponent component) {
    if (component instanceof HtmlGraphicImage) {
        return (String) component.getAttributes().get("alt");
    }
    else {
        return super.exportValue(context, component);
    }
}

}
```

The above is taken from [Issue 4013:    Support for CellEditor and Images in Exporter](https://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?id=4013&can=1&q=label=TargetVersion-4.0.9%20status%3aFixed&colspec=ID%20Stars%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20TargetVersion%20Owner%20Summary)

---

Know also that this feature is already released in the *PrimeFaces ELITE 4.0.9 and 3.5.25*